# h2o initialization parameters not optimal

Tags: r, h2o

My laptop has 8GB RAM with 4 cores.

My h2o version is as follows,`

```
Package: h2o
Type: Package
Version: 3.10.0.8
Branch: rel-turing
Date: Mon Oct 10 13:47:51 PDT 2016
License: Apache License (== 2.0)
Depends: R (>= 2.13.0), RCurl, jsonlite, statmod, tools, methods, utils`
```

I initialized it as follows,

```
h2o.init(nthreads = -1,max_mem_size = "8g")
```

But the output i get is as follows,

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         13 hours 21 minutes 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.0.8 
    H2O cluster version age:    21 days, 13 hours and 33 minutes  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_hp_ubq027 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   1.33 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    4 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    R Version:                  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
```

Why is the allowed cores only 2 and allowed memory only 1.33gb while almost 8GB is available?

Answer (score 2):

It says it has been running 13hrs. So what you are seeing is a cluster that is already running, and was (probably) started with default settings.

So, before doing your h2o.init() command you need to do h2o.shutdown():

```
h2o.shutdown()
h2o.init(nthreads = -1,max_mem_size = "8g")
```

(Remember when you shut down H2O that all models and data are lost, so use `h2o.exportFile()` and/or `h2o.saveModel()` if any of it cannot easily be re-created.)

**UPDATE:** I just noticed you said you had an 8GB laptop? I'd recommend not allocating more than 90% to H2O if the machine is dedicated, to be sure there is some left for the OS, Flow web server, etc.. (The [EC2 scripts](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/ec2/ami/start-h2o-bg.sh) use 90%.) And if you intend to do other stuff on your notebook (run RStudio, check email, use StackOverflow in a browser window, etc.) subtract the memory for all that first. (My notebook is 8GB, and my general-purpose machine, so I usually give H2O "4g" if I think I'll be making a lot of models, "2g" or "3g" otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `nthreads` defaulting to 2 -- to the best of my knowledge, that is a CRAN policy restriction, which is why it's set to 2 instead of -1 (recommended).